# Is that possible to implement a stack with lambda expressions only?

Tags: haskell, lambda-calculus

This might not be a very practical problem, I'm just curious if I can implement a stack with only lambda expressions.

A stack supports 3 operations: `top`, `pop` and `push`, So I begin with defining the stack to be a 3-tuple:

```
data Stack a = Stack a (a -> Stack a) (Stack a)
             | Empty
```

Here `Empty` stands for the empty stack so we at least have one inhabitant to begin with.

Under this definition, eveything looks good except for `push` operation:

```
import Control.Monad.State
import Control.Monad.Writer
import Data.Maybe

data Stack a = Stack a (a -> Stack a) (Stack a)
             | Empty

safePop :: Stack a -> Maybe (Stack a)
safePop Empty = Nothing
safePop (Stack _ _ s) = Just s

safeTop :: Stack a -> Maybe a
safeTop Empty = Nothing
safeTop (Stack x _ _) = Just x

push :: a -> Stack a -> Stack a
push x s = _

stackManip :: StateT (Stack Int) (Writer [Int]) ()
stackManip = do
    let doPush x = modify (push x)
        doPop    = do
            x <- gets safeTop
            lift . tell . maybeToList $ x
            modify (fromJust . safePop)
            return x
    doPush 1
    void doPop
    doPush 2
    doPush 3
    void doPop
    void doPop

main :: IO ()
main = print (execWriter (execStateT stackManip Empty))
```

So when I complete the code, I should be able to run it and get something like `[1,3,2]`

However, I find myself expanding the definition of `push` infintely:

`push` should construct a new stack, with first element being the item just pushed onto the stack and third element the  current stack:

```
push :: a -> Stack a -> Stack a
push x s = Stack x _ s
```

To fill in the hole, we need the stack being created, so I need a let-expression:

```
push :: a -> Stack a -> Stack a
push x s = let s1 = Stack x (\x1 -> Stack x1 _ s1) s
           in s1
```

To fill in the new hole, I need another let-expression:

```
push :: a -> Stack a -> Stack a
push x s = let s1 = Stack x (\x1 ->
                             let s2 = Stack x1 _ s1
                             in s2) s
           in s1
```

So you can see that there's always a hole in my `push` definition however I expand it.

I kind of understand the magic behind `Data.Function.fix` and guess some similiar magic can be applied here, but can't figure that out.

I'm wondering

- is this possible?
- If the answer is yes, what's the magic behind it?

Comment: Note that your `doPop` function doesn't actually change the state, so it's more of a `doPeek`.

Comment: You could also just use a `[a]` with `pop = tail`, `push = (:)`, `top = head`.

Comment: @Cactus `doPop` fixed, I was focusing on that `push` and didn't get a chance to check if my `stackManip` works. And I just want to have fun by not using list to implement stack.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can implement it entirely using function types with a Church encoding:

```
{-# LANGUAGE Rank2Types #-}

newtype Stack a = Stack (forall r. (a -> Stack a -> r) -> r -> r)

cons :: a -> Stack a -> Stack a
cons x (Stack f) = Stack (\g nil -> _)

peek :: Stack a -> Maybe a
peek (Stack f) = f (\x _ -> Just x) Nothing
```

This says that a `Stack` is a function that takes a function which takes the top element and the rest of the stack as its arguments. The `Stack` function's second argument is a default that is used if the stack is empty. I implemented the `peek` function but I left `cons` and the rest as an exercise (let me know if you need more help. Also, you leave in the underscore I put in `cons`, GHC will tell you what type it expects and list some possibly relevant bindings).

The rank-2 type is says that, given a `Stack a`, we can give it a function that returns any type of value, unconstrained by the `a` type variable. This is handy because we might not want to work with the same type. Consider a stack of lists and we want to use the function in `Stack` to get the length of the top element. More importantly, it says that a function like `cons` can't manipulate the result in any way. It must return the `r` type value it gets from the function (or from the default value, if the stack is empty), unchanged.

Another good exercise is to implement `toList :: Stack a -> [a]` and `fromList :: [a] -> Stack a` and show that those two functions form an isomorphism (meaning that they are inverses of each other).

In fact, as far as I know, all Haskell data types have a representation as a Church encoding. You can see three of the basic ways of combining types (sum types, product types and "type recursion") in action in this `Stack` type.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! the type signature of your `Stack` looks like something between `foldr` and `foldMap`, maybe I can also make it an instance of `Foldable`, will try it tomorrow. BTW why is this called "Church encoding"?

Comment: @Javran It is named after Alonzo Church, who was the first person to use this technique to encode data structures in lambda calculus. `Stack a` is isomorphic to `[a]`, so anything that applies to `[a]` should apply to `Stack a` (and visa-versa).

Comment: I see, I have mistakenly thought Chunrch encoding and Church numerals as the same thing. Now I get it.

Comment: Church numerals are the Church encoding of `data N = Z | S Z` :)

Comment: Here is my answer: [answer](https://gist.github.com/Javran/d241ef0477a16439d442) kind of getting the idea of Church encoding.

Comment: if I understand it correctly, for data type `data T = A a1 a2 ... | B b1 b2 ... | ...` you can encode into a function whose type is `forall r. (a1->a2->...->r)->(b1->b2->...->r)->...->r`

Comment: @Javran This is a very late reply, but I wanted to say that it's very perceptive that you compared it to `foldr` and `foldMap`. It is an implementation of the stack structure as its fold (the function contained in `Stack` is the fold for the type).

Answer (score 4):

The result of `push` is exactly what you want to keep `push`ing to, so you can tie the knot like this:

```
push :: a -> Stack a -> Stack a
push x s = let s' = Stack x (flip push s') s in s'
```

If you want to tie the knot via `Data.Function.fix`, you can transform the above definition like this:

```
push :: a -> Stack a -> Stack a
push x s = fix $ \s' -> Stack x (flip push s') s
```

Comment: I feel dumb what I didn't realize I can use `push` recursively.